# Error CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: postgresql, jooq, micronaut

I am trying to create a database from a Java application running in Micronaut framework using jOOQ.

The code

```
contextSupplier.get().createDatabaseIfNotExists(this.databaseName).execute();
```

with a PostgreSQL datasource fails with:

> org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [do $$ begin create database "mydb"; exception when sqlstate '42P07' then null; end $$]; ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Is there a simple way to turn transactions off within jOOQ just for this statement?

Comment: Why does it run inside a transaction? Can you please show your code?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, that basically IS the entire code. I do not touch any transactional behavior other than what jOOQ does out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.14, the [`DSLContext.createDatabaseIfNotExists()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#createDatabaseIfNotExists(org.jooq.Name)) method is supported by these dialects (see its `@Support` annotation):

```java
@Support({AURORA_POSTGRES,COCKROACHDB,MARIADB,MEMSQL,MYSQL,SQLDATAWAREHOUSE,SQLSERVER})
```

So, this statement is not yet supported in jOOQ for PostgreSQL - if I remember correctly, for this precise reason. Perhaps there's a different way to emulate the statement, but it hasn't been implemented yet.